# Flash Builder 4.6 - List control has ItemRenderer with text box - scrolling of list makes txt box values show all over

Tags: flash, actionscript, builder, itemrenderer

I have a list control, and an item renderer.  Within the item renderer, I have a text box for the quantity that the person wants of each item.  On each qty update (focus in an focus out events on the text box), I am updating the values for the data.  In the main program I show totals based on this.

The totalling code works correctly, however when I scroll the list the values show up all over the page.  Attached is a screenshot of the values all jumbled up after a simple scroll down.  Also, below is the complete item renderer.  I have found alot of notes on the web about this but everything I try doesn't help!

Here is a link to the picture of the problem:  [Scrolling Error](http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-4986103-272887/408-605/scrollingerror.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer name="PlowResultsRenderer"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >


<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;
   import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
   import valueObjects.Tag;
   import valueObjects.TagProjectItem;
   import classes.QtyChangeEvent; 

   [Bindable]
   public var lineQty:Number;
   [Bindable]
   public var lineList:Number;
   [Bindable]
   public var lineDealerCost:Number;

   public var textPlaceholder:String = "0";


   override public function set data( value:Object ) : void {
    super.data = value;

    var thisItem:TagProjectItem = data as TagProjectItem;

    if (thisItem.IsOnHand || thisItem.IsOnOrder)
    {
     currentState = "green";
    }else if (thisItem.IsOnDealerFloorplan)
    {
     currentState = "white";
    }else
    {
     currentState = "red";
    }
    //  #EEA2AD  old red

    lineList = Number(thisItem.ListPrice);
    lineDealerCost = Number(thisItem.DealerCost);
    lineQty = 0;



    validateNow();
   }


   /*protected function dataChangeHandler(evt:Event):void {

    var  thisItem:TagProjectItem = data as TagProjectItem;

    if (thisItem.IsOnHand || thisItem.IsOnOrder)
    {
     currentState = "green";
    }else if (thisItem.IsOnDealerFloorplan)
    {
     currentState = "white";
    }else
    {
     currentState = "red";
    }
    //  #EEA2AD  old red

    lblModelNumber.text = thisItem.ModelNumber;

    //lblListPrice.text = America.format(thisItem.ListPrice);
    lblListPrice.text = America.format(thisItem.PromoPrice);

    lblSWDescription.text = thisItem.SWDescription;
    lblSWCategory.text = thisItem.SWCategory;

    lineList = Number(thisItem.ListPrice);
    lineDealerCost = Number(thisItem.DealerCost);
    lineQty = 0;

    validateNow();
   }*/




   protected function doFocusIn(event:FocusEvent):void
   {

    textPlaceholder = txtQty.text;
    if (textPlaceholder == "0"){
     txtQty.text = "1";
    }
   }

   protected function doFocusOut(event:FocusEvent):void
   {

    if (txtQty.text != textPlaceholder){
     //here the text has been changed.
     var changeEvent:QtyChangeEvent = new QtyChangeEvent(QtyChangeEvent.CHANGE, Number(txtQty.text) - Number(textPlaceholder), lineDealerCost, lineList);
     parent.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    }
    textPlaceholder = "0";
    if (txtQty.text == ""){
     txtQty.text = "0";
    }
   }

  ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
  <mx:CurrencyFormatter id="America" precision="2" 
         rounding="none"
         decimalSeparatorTo="."
         thousandsSeparatorTo=","
         useThousandsSeparator="true"
         useNegativeSign="true"
         currencySymbol=""
         alignSymbol="left"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:states>
  <s:State name="green" />
  <s:State name="white" />
  <s:State name="red" />
</s:states>
<s:layout>
  <s:HorizontalLayout gap="0"
       paddingTop="1" paddingBottom="1"
       verticalAlign="middle" />
</s:layout>
<s:Panel skinClass="PanelNoTitleBar" horizontalCenter="0" width="100%">
  <s:Rect id="rect" width="100%">
   <s:fill>
    <s:SolidColor color.green="#C1FFC1" color.red="#FFC1C1" color.white="#FFEC8B">
    </s:SolidColor>
   </s:fill>
  </s:Rect>
  <s:HGroup width="100%">
   <s:VGroup>
    <s:Label text="Qty" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="8" paddingTop="4" paddingBottom="1" >
    </s:Label>
    <s:TextInput id="txtQty" width="34" height="30"
        fontSize="11" maxChars="3" restrict="0-9" softKeyboardType="number"
        widthInChars="3" text="{lineQty}"
        focusIn="doFocusIn(event)" focusOut="doFocusOut(event)">
    </s:TextInput>
   </s:VGroup>
   <s:VGroup width="100%">
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
     <s:Label id="lblModelNumber" text="{data.ModelNumber}" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="4" paddingBottom="1"  />
     <s:Spacer width="100%">
     </s:Spacer>
     <s:Label text="List Price: " paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="8" paddingTop="4" paddingBottom="1" />
     <s:Label id="lblListPrice" text="{America.format(data.PromoPrice)}" textAlign="right" fontWeight="bold" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="8" paddingTop="4" paddingBottom="1"   />
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Label id="lblSWCategory" text="{data.SWCategory}" paddingLeft="11" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="1" paddingBottom="1" />
    <s:Label id="lblSWDescription" text="{data.SWDescription}" paddingLeft="11" paddingRight="2" paddingTop="1" paddingBottom="4"  textAlign="right" /> 
   </s:VGroup>
  </s:HGroup>
</s:Panel>


</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: by the way, stack overflow won't let me post the picture I have of the numbers being shown all over the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an iOS application? If so, there is a bug with the scrolling of native text controls. The following should fix it:

```
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        @namespace local "*";
        s|TextInput {
            skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin");
        }
        s|TextArea {
            skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin");
        }
    </fx:Style>
```

Comment: Eduardo - I tried to add this into both the main View code, and the ItemRenderer itself.  Doesn't seem to help for some reason.  The application is built in FlashBuilder and targeted at both iOS and Droid platforms.  The scrolling issues occur on droid devices as well as iOS devices.

Comment: Please add it at the Application tag level. You can also specify the skin manually in each TextInput and TextArea control.

Comment: I am not sure if I remember correctly but, if you do not use the native controls, like I suggest, I think you cannot use the softKeyboardType property (not 100% sure, please try)

Comment: OK, now I think I have the scrolling being all over the place fixed.  HOWEVER - when I enter in a quantity in one of the text boxes, then scroll the list, the number shows up in the wrong text boxes?  Any ideas abou that?

Comment: I took off the softkeyboard and that didn't seem to help.  Scrolling issue of the numbers being all over hte place is fixed, but the numbers show up in the wrong text boxes now.

Comment: That could happen if you set your list to recycle the item renderer objects and do not initialize all their values in the data setter. I generally prefer to keep all state-related information in the data provider, and just use the item renderer for display (and input) purposes. If the item renderer carries state, you usually end up with this kind of problem.

Comment: Eduardo's answer worked, here is how it worked:

Step 1:  add Eduardo's code into the Application.mxml file.  
Step 2:  in the view that houses the list, on the list control istself, set "usevirtuallayout=false".

Once this is done, the list view will remember where the text boxes belong and where the values belong within them.  Thanks again Eduardo!!!